# I'm making an infographic on Bitcoin. How can I download all Bitcoin transactions to do some analysis?

Tags: blockchain

I would like to do some analysis of Bitcoin transactions in the last 3 months and share my insights by preparing an infographic. What would be the best way to get all Bitcoin transactions in the past 3 months?

Comment: Aren't bitcoin transactions anonymous? maybe you should ask some bicoin exchange market for some data.

Comment: @blogger: All transactions are stored publicly in the blockchain. They are not anonymous, but pseudonymous (each address is a pseudonym for a person, and therefore trackable, even though obfuscated).

Comment: @Edward: I saw a similar question a while back, the person was informed to look into a software called "ABE", I can't find the question right now though and don't know much about the tool myself.

Answer (score 1):

A key element of the Bitcoin protocol is the block chain, which is a public transaction database. This contains most all transactions made in bitcoins and also includes information such as the sending and receiving addresses. You can find historical transaction data for the past 3 months by using a block chain explorer like [ABE](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe) or [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info).

I would recommend ABE, only because it is written in Python, which will make it a lot easier to interface with for data analysis purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at historic data for Mt Gox if you are looking to correlate pricing data, which is available from their public API.  There is a function that returns all of the transactions that have occurred since a particular timestamp.  Other exchanges may or may not expose historical data. Otherwise you need to perform blockchain analysis using blockexplorer.info or [ABE](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe) if you have a local copy of the blockchain.